# How to remove Master Boot Manager from BIOS

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

after I spend 2 days like 6 hours per day to figured out and tried all the methods found on the internet I'm put my hope in you guys!

My machine is "Acer Aspire 7 A715-75G" using UEFI Bios. It comes with UEFI SHELL 2.7.

I've installed Microsoft Windows 10 couple of times to figure it out and try to get ride of Microsoft Windows 10 Boot Manager from BIOS. At this moment the HDD is only with UEFI SHELL 2.7 on it as it comes and unallocated space.enter image description here

[BIOS INFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAqJ7.jpg)

[BIOS MAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGrh.jpg)

[BIOS SECURITY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN9Ju.jpg)

[Windows BOOT Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiXsG.jpg)

[UEFI SHELL 2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWUiN.jpg)

Comment: Hi 2 things please do not post pictures of text include the text in the question. Second what has this got to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I saw a post with a guy installing UBUNTU and someone helped him with some commands. Maybe inside the UEFI are some commands that can remove that Windows Boot Manager. And I can try installing Ubuntu as well if the thing can work for me.

Comment: Post your question here on a forum where thay answer windows questions. https://superuser.com/

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot & http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/efibootmgr.8.html

Comment: Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G NVE not seen Boot parameter: nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429323 Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot